# Save Textbox value

Tags: javascript, textbox, save

how could i save my textbox value in localmemory if possible?
thanks for help

```js
addOne = function(){ document.myForm.inputbox.value = document.myForm.inputbox.value*1 + 1 ; }
```

```html
   <form name="myForm" action="" method=""> 
<input name="inputbox" readonly type="text" id="textarea" value="0" style="border-radius:15px; font-size:100;border-color:black;font-family:hotdog; color:white; border: 0px none;background-color:#0099FF;"></form>



</div>
    <div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
        <img src="diamond.
  png"  width="700"onclick="addOne()" class="change">
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do - is this along the lines of "If I fill the form in and submit, show the form again but save some/all of the values?"

eg if I try to login with my username and password, it clears the password field but retains my username?

Comment: im simply trying to make my website remembers how much time i clicked and shows it in the textbox so for example it shows 192 but i have no idea how to do that since my value is always 0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it persistent across page refreshes and so on, you should use cookies, here you have a good example:

[How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, this seems like it could work. The only problem is that i am a complete beginner with javascript and all these get.Date() things really confuse me could you somehow explain to me how can i use it on my code? thanks in advance :)